# Material UI TableCell can't force a string to display in a new line like list items

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I'm working with a "Books" table in Material UI. It has 3 columns: "Book Number", "Title", and "Chapters". I would like each chapter to be displayed in individual lines like list items, like so:

**Chapter 1**

**Chapter 2**

**Chapter 3**

and not

**Chapter 1 Chapter 2 Chapter 3**

I tried different approaches such as adding "\n", storing it in variable, and/or enclosing it in a template literal, like so:

```
const row2 = "Chapter 1\nChapter 2";
const row4 = `Chapter 1\nChapter 2\nChapter 3`;

const rows = [
  createData("1", "Book 1", "Not Applicable"),
  createData("2", "Book 2", row2),
  createData("3", "Book 3", "Chapter 1\nChapter 2"),
  createData("4", "Book 4", row4)
];
```

Here's the complete [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-sound-to63g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: Insert Chapters into an array.  Ex: createData("3", "Book 3", [ "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2" ]  ). Then use map function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a `Chapters` component that would accept a `value` prop — this `value` would be then converted to `array` using `split("\n")` and will be used to display each chapter as list item.

```js
function Chapters({ value }) {
  const chapters = value.split("\n");

  return (
    <List>
      {chapters.map((chapter, i) => (
        <ListItem key={i}>{chapter}</ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
}
```

Then on my `columns.map`, I would check for `column.label === "Chapters"`; if it is `true`, I would reassign the `value` calling my `Chapters` component.

```js
...
{
  rows.map((row) => {
    return (
      <TableRow hover role="checkbox" key={row.annex}>
        {columns.map((column) => {
          let value = row[column.id];

          if (column.label === "Chapters") {
            value = <Chapters value={value} />;
          }

          return <TableCell key={column.id}>{value}</TableCell>;
        })}
      </TableRow>
    );
  });
}
```

[image: Edit cool-cloud-gjz9m]

Comment: I want it to work without using `.map()` is that possible?

Comment: My line of code is something like this : `regions.length == 1 && unique(regions) ? regions[0] : unique(regions) + ", " ` I want every new region to be added on new line in same table cell without using `.map` and new line should be after the **comma** ' , '

Comment: @Aadi it would be easy for someone to help if you could post it as a question, provide a minimal, reproducible example and your expected output. I'll be the one to check first if you could do that. 

Comment: Thank you, I have resolved the issue. @bertdida

Answer (score 0):

Converting the array into a list is a good option, but you will also need to add a little css to avoid adding a ton of padding to your cell.

I needed this recently on a couple of tables, the cell formats were unreliable to detect from the API return, so I added an extra key in the column definitions then ran the cell value through that using the column format in a switch statement.

The array case then just looks like:

```
val = (
    <List className="table-cell-list">
      {val.map((item, i) => (
        <ListItem className="table-cell-list" key={i}>{item}</ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
```

And the css:

```
.table-cell-list {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

The roles column on this table is an array field, multiple values split out on new lines without excess spacing:

[image]